# VBScript with PHP on Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, vbscript

Is there any way to execute VBScript in PHP - I am using Apache Server on Windows Machine

I am trying to execute this simple VBScript on PHP Powered Apache Server, but not able to do so

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello</title>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Sub submit_btn_onclick()
    document.write("<h1>I <3 Web Programming!</h1>")
    usr = document.getElementById("user_name").value
    If usr <> "" Then

        output = document.getElementById("user_name").value
    else
        output = "Error!"
    End If
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" maxsize="10">
    <input type="button" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="">
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. VBScript is proprietary to Microsoft. You'll need to either write your code in PHP (or regular Javascript which from your example you could do) or find a Microsoft webhost

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys! Is there anyway to Power Apache Server with both PHP and Classic ASP Support? I looking on web for such solution.

Comment: just use JavaScript or jQuery. It should be easy to do what your are using VBscript for.

Comment: Actually the code written above is just a sample, i am trying to do bigger things than that - Like creating a object and doing some things

Comment: Like, I am creating object of "XYZ" Windows Application and using methods of that object.

Comment: this looks like client-side code. This may work if you view the page in IE